# Burninate: [votes]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

We have a [votes](/questions/tagged/votes) tag.  Looking at the small handful of questions that this covers, I feel like that this tag should be burninated and blacklisted; it can't stand on its own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were 23 questions tagged [votes](/questions/tagged/votes). I removed the tag from them, so it should disappear.

[image: tag burninated]